# Function length limitation in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, function

Is it possible to limit function/method length (C++) in Microsoft Visual Studio at compile time? (some compilator restriction, lets say to N lines)

Comment: Why do you ask?

Comment: @StoryTeller because I don`t like huge functions, I want to restrict it a little to other team  members, or just show them warning. Maybe it is not a good idea, I dont know. But usually, they use long finction when they dont have to.

Comment: Nobody likes them. I think you and your team better implement a better code review process instead. It will help with overall quality, more than a warning about function length.

Comment: @StoryTeller Exactly. Keep it as one of the requirements in a review. A soft limit at N lines of code and a hard limit at 2*N lines of code, for example.

Comment: I don't like the idea of burdening code reviewers with checks that can be done automatically; also, why wait for a code review when the IDE can give you an immediate feedback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function length limitation in Visual Studio is *not* an option.